# How to securely store secret in heroku

Tags: heroku

I know that there options like

> heroku config:set

But the config vars will still appears in the UI for heroku dashboard, visible to anyone who have access.

Let's say I only want one person (i.e. the owner) to set and see this variable to store a secret, is it possible?